# How to view the code behind a PDF document in IOS

Tags: pdf, nsstring, cgpdf

I have a PDF page that I've converted into a stream:

```
CGPDFContentStreamRef contentStream = CGPDFContentStreamCreateWithPage(pdfPage);
```

How can I view that stream as an NSString? I'd like to see the code that represents the PDF.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930282/parse-whole-pdf-page-to-nsstring-on-an-iphone ?

Comment: that guy is using callbacks from a scanner. I want to get the string that the scanner is reading. I could probably convert the contentStream to NSData and then display it, but to do that I need to know the length of the contentStream....

Answer (score 2):

It's not as easy as that. A stream can be any binary data, there might be multiple chained compression formats used. See http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf (Page 23ff) for potential formats.

Your best option is `CGPDFScanner` other than re-implementing a PDF parser/lexer from scratch (We did that in the commercially available PSPDFKit SDK for iOS and Android - it's complicated.)